# Extracting one file from multiple tar files that are within one tar file

Tags: osx, tar

I have a '.tar' file that contains multiple '.tar.gz' files. Within each of these '.tar.gz' there is a '.faa' file that I need. I don't want to unpack everything else.

I have been searching through a lot of old questions here but I seem to be getting stuck on one part of my code. Based on what I've read I wrote this:

```
tar -zxOf /pathtofolder/folder1.tar ".tar.gz" | tar -zxvf - '.faa'
```

However, it is only pulling from just one of the '.tar.gz' and not the other 6:

```
x 2758568008/2758568008.genes.faa
```

I then tried a for loop in case that was it:

```
tar -zxOf /Users/gchaput/Desktop/TestFolder/img_data_29800-13.tar | for file in '*.tar.gz'; do tar -zxf "$file" '*.faa'; done
```

But I get the error:

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '*.tar.gz'
```

I have a macOS 10.14.1 and so wildcard is not an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `*.tar.gz` and retry with your loop.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Ah it worked! Thank you so much- I can't believe what a quick fix that was. Goes to show how helpful it is to have other eyes on what you're doing.

Comment: To complement @WeijunZhou 's comment, the single quotes are preserving the `* ` character to be expanded. Take a look at the following SE Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/2231796

Comment: I can't understand use of `| for` first tar command do extract file, piping look useless here. (not useless it add confusion).

Answer (score 0):

Use " " in stand of ' ' which is always good for linux!

Comment: can you explain how changing the quoting would fix the problem at hand?